# Расчет координат точки пересечения нескольких окружностей

Tags: c#, математика, геолокация, геометрия

В общем условие такое: выполняю парсинг одного сайта с трёх геопозиций (с известными местоположением), в ответ json мне присылает с каждой такой геопозиции расстояние до объекта в километрах/метрах.

Собственно задачка: Необходимо вычислить географические координаты искоvого объекта, пусть и с небольшими погрешностями (для последующего отображения на карте).

Короче имеется точка (X;Y) и радиус.
Например:
Замер от 1ой позиции(x1,y1) до объекта: 1,2 км
Замер от 2ой позиции(x2,y2) до объекта: 3 км
Замер от 3ой позиции(x3,y4) до объекта: 100 м
Объект один и тот же, соответственно пересечению быть! (хотя и с погрешностями)

Помогите сформулировать математическую функцию (включая расчет погрешности) или же сразу алгоритм на C# :)

Comment: Добавьте в заголовок, что `трёх окружностей`

Comment: У трёх окружностей может и не быть точки пересечения. Вам нужна какая-то оптимизация типа наименьших квадратов. Сформулируйте ваш критерий оптимальности.

Comment: В реальных данных её точно не будет. Поэтому нужно искать пересечение плоских фигур, образованных окружностями r-d и r+d.

Comment: @vp_arth: Так получится целая область

Comment: Именно, предположительная область местонахождения объекта.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваша задача эквивалента тому, что решает GPS (ГЛОНАС) приемник при спутниковой навигации.

Дано неизвестная координата объекта (в Вашем плоском случае x и y) и расстояния Ri до объектов (спутников) с известными координатами (xi,yi) (все с погрешностями). Решается задача путем минимизации критерия суммарной квадратичной ошибки `Min{ Sum[(Xi-X)^2+(Yi-Y)^2-Ri^2]^2 }`. Для получения уравнений нужно взять от этого критерия частные производные по x и у и приравнять их нулю.

В результате Вы получите систему из двух кубических уравнений относительной двух неизвестных x и y.

Как решать такую систему - это уже следующий вопрос :)

Comment: Но ведь если замера три, то и система получится из трех уравнений, я правильно понимаю Вас?

Comment: Неправильно :). Уравнений будет два, слагаемых в исходном критерии три. Причем чем больше замеров из разных точек тем, точнее будет расчет, но уравнений все равно будет только два. Вы продифференцируйте критерий по x и y, приравняйте результат нулю и все сразу станет понятно.

Comment: Вон оно что. Буду пытаться решить. Спасибо большое!

Comment: Если ответ Вам помог, то пожалуйста проголосуйте за него, если Вы конечно хотите, чтобы Вам помогали и дальше

Comment: Я бы рад, однако недостаточно рейтинга. Как появится - сразу отмечу!)